# git (+ LaTeX) branching/merging workflow

Tags: git, latex, git-workflow

### Current workflow

I'm using `git` to control-version my thesis written in `LaTeX`. **I'd like to improve my currently sub-optimal `git` workflow**, since it requires too many merges (i.e. it takes time + it pollutes the log history).

Currently, my workflow is the following:
[image]

- I commit to `master` branch  "finalized" releases only (i.e. when I send my supervisor a current not-broken version of my work);
- These commits come from a `develop` branch that aggregates several `feature/x` branches and contains pre-release patches.
- Several `feature/x`, corresponding to the various parts of my thesis, e.g.:

  - `feature/state-of-the-art`
  - `feature/conclusion`
  - `feature/page-layout`
  - `feature/global-settings`

In each `feature`-branch, I mostly change one file only (e.g. `part/SotA.tex` for the first branch). Yet I like to work with multiple branch, so that it's easier for me to keep track of work done on this or that part/topic.

---

### Drawbacks

This workflow however has some drawbacks I'd like to sort out:

- *To have an overview of my work*, I have to merge each `feature/x` branch into `develop`. This makes me do a lot of merge commits that pollutes my history. Indeed, my workflow looks actually rather like this (where `d3`, `d4`, and `d5` are just here to enable me to have a global overview of my work):
  [image]
- Similarly, *if I want to import modifications done in another branch* (e.g. loading a package), I have to merge back the `develop` branch into each `feature/x` branch:
  [image]

---

### Question

**Thus, I'd like to be able to**:

1. share changes of the `feature/n` branch with other `feature/x` branches,
2. be able to have an overview of my work remaining on `feature/n` branch (instead of `$git checkout master` + `$git merge feature/n`)

**without so doing so many merging.**
I know I could use less branches, but, as explained above, they are useful to me and I'd like to keep them. I think `rebase -p` could be a solution, but I'm not mastering `git` enough to figure out how to proceed - since each `feature/x` branch stems from and merge into `develop`.

---

NB: I am the only commiter in this workflow, so I can rewrite history as I want.

Comment: For what it's worth, I would (and do) use `git rebase` without `-p` (but also without having merges that get rebased here). I make temporary merges, then discard them, when testing features.

Comment: @torek: Thks, but the point here is to keep branches alive, in order to be able to review the whole development of my chapter by reading the history of a particular branch. I'd thus also `merge --no-ff` on this purpose...

Comment: You can find [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34650034#34650034) the archive of a chat discussion hold on `tex.SE` about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To have an overview of my work, I have to merge each feature/x branch into develop.

There's nothing sacred about a commit. Easiest is probably to make your overviews with a discardable branch name,

```
git checkout -B overview develop; git merge feature/x feature/y feature/z
```

and then when you're done looking just abandon it, checkout something else.

> Similarly, if I want to import modifications done in another branch (e.g. loading a package), I have to merge back the develop branch into each feature/x branch

Naaahh. I'd do the loaded packages work with a submodule and just not worry about it any more, have a "packages" repo for that stuff and just remember to `git add` the current packages set before committing, or to do it without submodules you could just `git rm -r packages; git checkout develop -- packages` to copy across the version you want.  For other changes, small drive-by fixes and such, often enough `git cherry-pick` or even `git cherry-pick --no-commit` is all you really want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I do appreciate. However, I do not find it fully satisfactory: doing a `checkout overview` + `merge` + LaTeX compilation (+ PDF reviewing) and then `checkout feature/x`  is way to complicated - even with aliases - since I do a lot of intermediary compilation (about every 5 minutes). I'd like to leave my IDE (TeXstudio) as rarely as possible. Regarding submodules, they seem way to risky/complicated for me (as far as I've heard)...

Comment: So, you want to keep current work on chapters in different branches, but see the result of the combined current state without merging?  I must be missing something here.

Comment: And submodules are _easy_.  The screeds you see against them are from people whose intuitions won't shut up and let them see what's right in front of them.

Comment: 1) yes, but. The point would be to include work done on other branches, but from time to time only (e.g. at every release), in order to balance "keeping track of what's done on other branches" and "minimize work done/global merges". Somehow what is done with a `rebase`, but since branches are interdependent here, I've an issue. 2) you're right, I should give them a try and make my own opinion!